# drop database via bash with dash in database-name

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, mysql, database

I have a variable in a script with the list of folder names with dash in their names

```
DBDIR="some directory"
dbdash=`ls -l $DBDIR | egrep '^d' | grep '.-.' | awk '{print $9}'`
```

And I want to drop every database with the same names with the folders in the variable "dbdash"

```
dbhype=($dbdash)
for dbtry in ${!dbhype[*]}
    do            
        mysqladmin -u$dbUser -p$dbPass 'drop database if exists `'${dbhype[$dbtry]}'` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;'
done
```

But this error came out after running the script

> mysqladmin: Unknown command: 'drop database if exists folder_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLAT'

How can I delete these databases using script? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're mixing up `mysqladmin` and the regular `mysql`. The former does not take SQL, only specific custom commands.

Second, stop parsing the output of `ls`. You can use wildcards directly to get a list of files.

```
DBDIR="some directory"

for db_dir in "$DBDIR"/*-*/; do
    db_name=$(basename "$db_dir")
    # The other way:
    # db_name=${db_dir%/}; db_name=${db_dir##*/}

    echo "Dropping '$db_name'..."

    mysql -u"$user" -p"$pass" "drop database if exists $db_name;"
    # The other way:
    # mysqladmin -u"$user" -p"$pass" drop "$db_name"
done
```